# How to have a difftime column with different units

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with two time fields. I am trying to get the difference between these two times. The problem I am facing is the unit of the first row is used across the board in all rows. But the value is in a different unit.

Below is an example:

```
myt <- strptime("7/15/2016  7:51:33 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") - 
       strptime("7/15/2016  7:51:32 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

myt[2] <- strptime("7/15/2016  7:53:32 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") - 
          strptime("7/15/2016  7:51:32 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

myt

#Time differences in secs
#[1] 1 2

myt[1]
#Time difference of 1 secs

myt[2]
#Time difference of 2 secs
```

In this case, the answer for `myt[2]` is 2 minutes and not 2 seconds. Is it possible to

1. have different rows have different units?
2. if not atleast have the correct value for the given unit (120 secs in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. I didn't know that this is happening.

A possible solution could be to use `difftime()` and specify the time difference 'unit' that you want.

```
> myt <- difftime(strptime("7/15/2016 7:51:33 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), 
                  strptime("7/15/2016 7:51:32 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), 
                  units = "secs")
> myt[2] <- difftime(strptime("7/15/2016 7:53:32 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"),
                     strptime("7/15/2016 7:51:32 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), 
                     units = "secs")
> myt
Time differences in secs
[1]   1 120
```

Thanks for pointing this out. I'm quite newbie with datetime/POSIXct stuff and I would not have realized this

Comment: I think I know why it was showing 'wrongly'. When myt was created, the vector was intialized to have the attribute "secs"; addition of elements to the vector does not change the unit (i.e. only the numeric solution to the time difference is added?).

Comment: Thank you Carlo. I used your approach and converted the entire column to seconds and I can later convert it at a row level when I need.

Comment: @Sai, good to know that it works for you. All the best to whatever you are doing!

Answer (score 0):

Could you use multiple columns or does that not work for your problem?  If it would work:

```
myt <- data.frame(strptime("7/15/2016 7:51:33 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") - strptime("7/15/2016 7:51:32 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
myt[,2] <- strptime("7/15/2016 7:53:32 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") - strptime("7/15/2016 7:51:32 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
colnames(myt) <- c("time1","time2")
myt
```

Comment: Thank you Phil. In my case, I am dealing with a large dataset and using multiple columns would not work.